# SQL Server will not allow me to use User & Login I have just created

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
USE master 

GO 

CREATE LOGIN Alex WITH PASSWORD = '1234567890' MUST_CHANGE, CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON; 
CREATE LOGIN Nick WITH PASSWORD = '1234567890' MUST_CHANGE, CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON; 
CREATE LOGIN Lora WITH PASSWORD = '1234567890' MUST_CHANGE, CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON;
```

Next I created the Users:

```
USE master 
GO 

CREATE USER Alex FOR LOGIN Alex; 
CREATE USER Nick FOR LOGIN Nick; 
CREATE USER Lora FOR LOGIN Lora;
```

Finally, I try to create the Users in my DB:

```
USE [Test2] 
GO 

CREATE USER Alex FOR LOGIN Alex WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo69; 
CREATE USER Nick FOR LOGIN Nick WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo69; 
CREATE USER Lora FOR LOGIN Lora WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo69;
```

This just gives me an error:

> Msg 15007, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 
>   'Alex' is not a valid login or you do not have permission.
>
> Msg 15007, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   'Nick' is not a valid login or you do not have permission.
>
> Msg 15007, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   'Lora' is not a valid login or you do not have permission.

This is illogical. They exist. How can I not have permission if I have just created them?

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you really have a schema called `dbo69`? Also, those initial statements would fail, there's no comma (`,`) between the `'1234567890' ` and `MUST_CHANGE`. Is *that* the problem here?

Comment: Also, database permissions can be different, just because *you* can create a `LOGIN` and `USER` in `master` doesn't mean you can create a `USER` in a different database.

Comment: Try `CREATE USER SimpleSimon WITHOUT LOGIN;` in `Test2` to see if you get the same error message (which will tell you this is a permissions issue and not some illogical inability for SQL Server to find the login). If that works, also try `SimpleSimon2` and add the `DEFAULT_SCHEMA` option.